# APIs consulta en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, api, backend

Tengo una pregunta, por ejemplo toda mi aplicación web existe en mi servidor, y un CRM de una empresa externa(servidor B) tendrá cierta parte de mis datos (información), ¿cómo es posible enviarle cierta información y ellos envían cierta información en tiempo real? Sé que podríamos usar API pero cómo podríamos asegurar que si hay nuevos registros de ambos lados recibamos una notificación, es decir, que nos avisen, para ampliar un poco más la idea. Servidor A <-> Servidor B (usuarios) Servidor B <-> Servidor A (pagos) Por ejemplo en mi aplicación tengo un endpoint [www.example.com/api/users](http://www.example.com/api/users) Y en el crm [www.crm.com/api/](http://www.crm.com/api/) pagos Si hay un nuevo usuario, avisar al CRM que hay un nuevo usuario en tiempo real. Si hay nuevos pagos de los usuarios, avisarnos. ¿Es posible hacer esa conexión? Gracias. Estoy usando Node js, mi base de datos está en Oracle y la empresa CRM usa .net y Oracle.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, es demasiado amplia y hasta podría basarse en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre. En [es.so] resolvemos problemas específicos, que se puedan reproducir. En cuanto a tu duda, debes investigar sobre patrones de arquitectura de software. Hay muchos desafíos en lo que planteas, pero no eres el primero con ese problema, por lo cuál puedes analizar las diferentes opciones que se han utilizado y aplicar aquella que más se ajuste a tus requerimientos